# How can I write a SQL query to translate a column containing Chinese language to English?

Tags: sql, translation, cjk

The column called 'name' contains many rows of chinese language I can't read or understand. I want to convert this whole column to english but I have no clue how

I tried to look online as I'm new to SQL but couldn't find much

Comment: SQL has no built-in translating.

Answer (score -1):

You could call the Google Translate API to make the translation.  You have to create a seperate column and then using Web.Contents to pass the Chinese text to Google Translate, it will return the English translation.

SQL itself has no intergrations for direct translation. You have to go for a workaround.

[Google Reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest)